# Residuals in LMM and GLMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, residuals, glmm

I found many answers and resources about model validation and the use of residuals to validate a model, but I still have some doubt about which kind of residual use for a linear mixed model, or, even harder, in GLMM. I started to study with "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R (2009). Zuur et al." proceeding with papers and other material, but things are getting darker and darker instead of clearer.

I'm actually using R with lme4 pachage and its functions lmer and glmer. I'm extracting residuals using resid. For example:

```
lmm1 <- lmer(flow_spec ~ snh + (1|sampling_round) + (1|ls),
 REML=T, data= flowers_vs_snh)
par(mfrow= c(1,2))
E_lmm1D <- resid(lmm1, type="deviance")
hist(E_lmm1D)
qqnorm(E_lmm1D)
qqline(E_lmm1D)
par(op)

shapiro.test(E_lmm1D)
```

Here I calculated deviance residuals.

So. Questions:

- Which kind of residuals are better to use with LMM, and in which situation?
- About GLMM, did the choice depend on which function I choose?

Comment: this seems to be an unreproducible example and a not very clear question. Residuals are extracted for an "object for which the extraction of model residuals is meaningful", what choices do you have, related to the question you ask?  "Did the choice depend on which function I choose?" - why not try it out and see if it did?

Comment: About GLMMs, see discussion here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Comment: @FlorianHartig Many thanks for your advice about your package.